# Compare two vectors with different length in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I have two vectors, one 12x1 and the other 2430x1. I want to take each element of the first vector and find which is the immediately *after* the matching element in the second vector, saving it in a third vector.

Example:

```
V1 = [1, 2, 3]
V2 = [1.2, 2.3, 2.5, 3.3, 3.4, 3.7 ......]
```

I would like to have the value for each `V1` element immediately after each corresponding `V2` element. I should then get

```
V3 = [1.2, 2.3, 3.3]
```

Comment: Is `V2` alway sorted in accending order?

Comment: @EBH Yes, but there may not be any common elements between the two carriers

Answer (score 2):

You can use [interp1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) setting the interpolation method as `'next'`:

```
%remove common elements
V3 = setdiff(V2,V1);
%get the next elements
result = interp1(V3,V3, V1,'next','extrap')
```

Thanks to @SardarUsama for his clarification and testing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the V1 vector as indices to go through V2... try this maybe:

```
For i =1:length (V1)
V3 (i) = V2 (V1 (i));
End
```

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're asking for though...

Comment: **1.** `For` is nothing in MATLAB. `for` is. **2.** `End` is nothing in MATLAB. `end` is. **3.** Using `i` as a variable name is a bad idea since it is reserved for imaginary numbers. **4.** Changing the size of an array in a loop is a bad idea. **5.** ***And above all***, even if you fix these  points, your answer doesn't give the expected output which is `V3 = [1.2, 2.3, 3.3]`